# I never encrypted my wallet.

Tags: encryption, passphrase

When I installed it I never encrypted it. I then funded the address and I now have 1.1 bitcoins. But when I tried to send or create a new address it asked for a passphrase. I tried every possible password I have ever used. It's very confusing because I added an extra address so I would of had to enter a passphrase 4 times to set one and create a new one. Have you ever heard of this? Can you or do you know anyone who could help

Comment: You wouldn't have needed the passphrase to add a key to the wallet because of something called the keypool.

Comment: What client are you using?

Comment: Next time use forgiving wallets like Armory or Electrum. The official wallet is a disaster.

Comment: Not sure what keypool is...so no

Comment: I'm using QT 4.8.3

Comment: Came across something similar myself recently, so might be able to help if you still have the same installation and haven't done too much to the hard drive? What situation is the computer in? did you leave it as is or have you overwritten everything?

Comment: This question was asked almost half a year ago.

Comment: so? as long as he hasn't deleted his bitcoinQt I may be able to get it back.

Answer (score 1):

you should try asking this question at bitcointalk.org. If there is a bug in the client then perhaps it will help if you try copying your wallet.dat somewhere and loading it into a new version of client or fresh install? It is a good idea to have your private key for each address you plan to store bitcoins in written down somewhere before you send bitcoins to them. You can then load that private key into any wallet in order to spend the bitcoins.

Comment: I tried that but it is still encrypted. It is strange. I created a second address so I would of have to reenter a password. I never did.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody else is saying it so far. So I will:  It it sounds like you got hacked.
Somebody or something copied your wallet.dat file and encrypted it before you had a chance to.  Now they control the funds and not you.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly it would appear you've been hacked.

Leaving ฿1.1 without a password on any wallet.DAT file (be it BTC or other altcoin) is essentially leaving your wallet on top of your car with $1000 hanging out.

Most likely scenario: new malware has targeted your unencrypted wallet.dat as crypto-currencies are [hot targets nowadays](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9246692/Bitcoin_malware_count_soars_as_cryptocurrency_value_climbs), for example [Pony Botnet](http://www.infosecurity-magazine.com/view/37132/new-instance-of-pony-botnet-steals-virtual-currencies-)...

In fact Pony Botnet 2.0 is damned frightening when you consider the [maliciousness and intelligence](https://blog.damballa.com/archives/2558) orchestrated recently.

Sorry to be the bearer or bad news.

**PS** w/ the pubkey of your ฿1.1 why not query [Blockchain](http://Blockchain.info)?